# Error while deploying objects

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

I just tried deploying an object that doesn't exist in my sandbox and the deployment failed with the following error:

File name: objects/CM123__c.object, Component name: CM123__c 
Message: 0664b0000000def does not exist or is not a valid override for action Edit.

Why am I getting this error? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you have any vf page for edit action in your exisiting org?

Comment: Yes, there is a VF page. Is there a way to tokenize the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that object which you are trying to deploying has some dependency on another object. Could you please verify if master details relationship are accordingly satisfy. It might be profile issue, try to migrate profile too if any related to this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options which you can apply in this situation.

1. if you don't want to deploy visualforce page edit your CM123__c.object with any text editor and remove visualforce reference.
2. Deploy visualforce along with your CM123__c.object.